# Not getting Analytical badge

Tags: support, analytical-badge

I viewed all the sections in  the FAQ of Stack Overflow but have still not been awarded the "Analytical" badge.

Is it that I need to see all the FAQs in Meta, Programmers and other Stack Exchange sites?

P.S: This is not a duplicate question, all the questions related to this I have seen, however I did not find a satisfying answer.

Comment: You need to _read_ all the sections, not just _view_.

Comment: And some sections are collapsed. You have to click on *show more* to read whole section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should read all the sections - expand them all and scroll down.
Second, badges are not awarded immediately - there's a script that is run from time to time. So even if you have read the entire FAQ, you will have to wait until the badge is awarded - this may take a few minutes to a few hours.